# is there an available laravel validation rules for old password?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

is there an available validation rules that lets you compare the input field and the column in the database if they match

like they should match the user id and the session and the inputted password and the password in the database?

Comment: You should not be storing plaintext passwords in the database, so you shouldn't be able to use any kind of input validation rules on the password to compare it to what is in the database.

Comment: for comparing old and new password use Hash::check($currentpassword, $password)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-exists) rule:

> The field under validation must exist on a given database table.

```
'form_field' => 'exists:table,column'
```

Comment: what i want is if it exist in other table and the session or id matches in the column id

Comment: Exists is a great way to do this, how would you apply it in the scenario @Christian has given regarding comparing old passwords and new passwords?

Comment: what if i have a old password of abc and i logged in to another account then i entered an old password without even validating if it's my account. if i just used exist then the password of other account will be change even if i don't own the account  becuase my condition is if it only exist

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this while I was looking for the same answer as well. This maybe a bit old, but as Christian mentioned in the comments, the solution by Alexey allows the user to use any existing password (even another user's) in the database as the current password. Hope this answer helps someone :)

So for Laravel 5.2 the below solution worked for me as [mentioned in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-exists):

```
'old_password' => 'required|exists:users,password,usr_id,'.$user_id,
```

This maybe different in Laravel 5.3+, as the [Laravel 5.3 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-exists) has the following validation for customizing the query. I haven't tried this, but it does not work for Laravel 5.2.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::exists('staff')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('account_id', 1);
        }),
    ],
]);
```